# How to copy Chrome cookies on Android to Chrome on Windows?

Tags: google-chrome, android, google-chrome-extensions, cookies

Is there a way to do this? I found a few extensions that can do it but doesn't work on Android Chrome. Is rooting required?

Comment: Just as a note, jailbreaking is for iPhones. For Android it's called `rooting` as you get root access. If you're just going to use an extension on Chrome itself, it shouldn't require root access.

Comment: What extension did you try ? I don't know if EditThisCookie works on Android but it works on Chrome just fine

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that by using Google Chrome on your Android device, since Google Chrome does not support extensions and does not allow you to export your cookies. I am also not aware of any way to access Chrome's cookies even by rooting your phone.

If you don't mind using a different browser, you could try to use Firefox for Android since it fully supports extension. You can run the same extensions on your phone than the one available for PC.

I have made a Firefox extension for this exact purpose. It is called Cookie-Editor. You can view, edit and delete your cookies directly on your phone. You can also import and export your cookies to be able to transfer them between your phone and your computer. Is is compatible with other Chrome extensions like EditThisCookie too, so you don't even have to switch browser on your PC.

> Cookie-Editor lets you efficiently create, edit and delete cookies for the current tab. Perfect for developing, quickly testing or even manually managing your cookies for your privacy.
>   Also supports Firefox for Android.

You can find the extension for [Firefox here](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/cookie-editor/)

Or for [Google Chrome here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-editor/hlkenndednhfkekhgcdicdfddnkalmdm)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loging in to chrome on the pc with the same google account you are loged in to the android phone and then enable sync on chrome options?